# Why am I receiving a compilation error when executing my PL/SQL Code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COMPANYEMPLOYEES 
(
  in_cname IN VARCHAR2
) AS 
  P_RESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN P_RESULT FOR
    SELECT ename, c.cid, in_cname
    FROM employee e
    JOIN company c on c.cid = e.cid 
    WHERE c.CNAME = in_cname;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(P_RESULT);
END COMPANYEMPLOYEES;
```

After you execute the script to create the sproc, you can run this by using the following command

```
EXEC COMPANYEMPLOYEES ‘Verizon’
```

or

```
EXEC COMPANYEMPLOYEES ‘ATT’
```

Comment: what compilation error you are getting?

Comment: This is what comes up--->Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors. I am using Oracle iSQL Plus Release 9.2.0.6

Comment: `Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors`. what are those compilation errors?

Comment: what's your database version? dbms_sql.return_result is only available in Oracle 12c

Comment: I am using Oracle iSQL Plus Release 9.2.0.6-- how can I get my code to work?

Comment: @Kross that's your client. Execute this statement to get your database version: select * from v$version;

Comment: BANNER
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

Given that `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` is only available in 12c and you're using version 11 I suggest that you change `COMPANYEMPLOYEES` to be a function, remove the call to `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`, and just return the opened cursor:

```
create or replace FUNCTION COMPANYEMPLOYEES 
    (in_cname IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  P_RESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN P_RESULT FOR
    SELECT ename, c.cid, in_cname
    FROM employee e
    JOIN company c on c.cid = e.cid 
    WHERE c.CNAME = in_cname;

  RETURN P_RESULT;
END COMPANYEMPLOYEES;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: After doing that, I received the following error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  create or replace FUNCTION COMPANYEMPLOYEES
*

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Comment: @Kross - You'd need to drop your procedure or use a different name for the function.  Functions and procedures have the same namespace.

Comment: Can you explain how I do that? I am new to SQL Programming. I am really struggling here.

Comment: @Kross - `drop procedure companyemployees`.  Then run your `create or replace function`.

Comment: When I did that, it said the following:                                                Procedure dropped.

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

Comment: Why do I keep getting a message that says "created with compilation errors"?

Comment: Try executing `SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'COMPANYEMPLOYEES' AND TYPE = 'FUNCTION'`, which will retrieve the errors associated with your function. Hopefully that will provide you with some help. Best of luck.